# Under what conditions are unix (Mac OS ) sytem calls restarted after getting interrupted by a signal ? What do the man page mean by "calls committed"?

Tags: c, macos, posix, signals, system-calls

I'm reading a book on unix systems and I'm at the part where signals are discussed. I'm a bit confused when it comes to what happens when a system call is running and a signal is received.
It says that the OS arranges for some system calls (for example, `read()`) to be restarted when receiving an interruption by a signal.

However when reading the man page for signal it goes:

> For some system calls, if a signal is caught while the call is
> executing
> and the call is prematurely terminated, the call is automatically
> restarted.  Any handler installed with signal(3) will have the SA_RESTART
> flag set, meaning that any restartable system call will not return on
> receipt of a signal.  The affected system calls include read(2), write(2),
> sendto(2), recvfrom(2), sendmsg(2), and recvmsg(2) on a communications
> channel or a low speed device and during a ioctl(2) or wait(2).  However,
> **calls that have already committed are not restarted, but instead return a
> partial success** (for example, a short read count).  These semantics could
> be changed with siginterrupt(3).

1. What is meant by "calls that have already committed"?
2. Is there any possibility that a read could not behave properly because of being interrupted by a signal?
3. If the read fails (or doesn't behave properly) because of a signal how can I avoid that?

Answers with sample codes are very appreciated.